# What does it mean to "remain alert to danger"?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranger, surprise

A ranger gains the following ability when traveling for an hour or more (**Natural Explorer** from PH and Unearthed Arcana Revised Ranger, emphasis mine):

> Even  when    you are engaged in  another activity while  traveling (such as  foraging,   navigating, or  tracking),  you *remain alert   to  danger*.

What does this mean in the game context, and how should it be interpreted practically for play?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Normally if involved in an activity during travel a character cannot participate in perception checks to, for example, notice when they are being followed.

> As adventurers travel through a dungeon or the
>   wilderness, they need to remain alert for danger, and
>   some characters might perform other tasks to help
>   the group's journey.
>
> Characters who turn their attention to other tasks as the
>   group travels are not focused on watching for danger.
>   These characters don't contribute their passive Wisdom
>   (Perception) scores to the group's chance of noticing
>   hidden threats. (PHB p.182-183)

A ranger with this ability may be engaged a travel activity (e.g. foraging, navigating, tracking, creating a map, ...) while still being allowed to participate in the party's perception checks.

> You gain the following benefits when traveling for an hour or more:
>
> ...
>
> - Even when you are engaged in another activity while traveling (such as foraging, navigating, or tracking), you remain alert to danger.

Comment: That is a good answer (and the one I use), any reference to that in the rules?

Comment: Thanks for adding that reference - don't have my PHB on me, and that's not in the SRD as far as I could tell :)

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the update. Sometimes I wish I had a PDF rule book I could search for phrases.

Comment: @tillmas the [5e System Reference Document](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SRD-OGL_V5.1.pdf) is often useful if you prefer a licit option, but it does leave many rules out (such as in this case).